# Is there a syntaxt error with my sequelize query near insert?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run sequelize insert query with replacements and i am getting sql syntax error.

I have tried to run raw query in editor its working fine.Cant figure out the issue with my code.

```
const queryToUpdateExistingTable = 
`INSERT INTO social_profile ( fk_user_id , fk_marital_status_id ,
fk_military_service_id , v_occupation , fk_education_id , v_bio , 
v_pets ,v_places_lived ) 
VALUES (:fk_user_id , :fk_marital_status_id, 
:fk_military_service_id, :v_occupation , :fk_education_id , :v_bio, 
:v_pets , :v_places_lived) 
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
queryToUpdateExistingTable, 

{type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
                                replacements: {
                                    fk_user_id: uProfileData.id ,
                                    fk_marital_status_id: uProfileData.fk_marital_status_id,
                                    fk_military_service_id: uProfileData.fk_military_service_id,
                                    v_occupation: uProfileData.v_occupation,
                                    fk_education_id: uProfileData.fk_education_id,
                                    v_bio: uProfileData.v_bio,
                                    v_pets: uProfileData.v_pets,
                                    v_places_lived: uProfileData.v_places_lived
                                }});});
```

Comment: There is a close quote missing for queryToUpdateExistingTable but otherwise it looks OK to me.  You might be able to identify the problem by temporarily commenting out some of the replacements until the syntax error disappears.

Comment: the sequelize is adding escape sequence in varchar.This was causing problem. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the query being generated and the error as well?

Comment: Also try to use code formatters like `Prettier` and linters `ESLint` for Node/Javascript/Typescript projects. You can set it up to automatically format your code on save. They make life much easier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix : In Migration, a raw query sequelize ad backslash escape in varchar which cause error while inserting that value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707210/how-to-fix-in-migration-a-raw-query-sequelize-ad-backslash-escape-in-varchar)