# How to fix : In Migration, a raw query sequelize ad backslash escape in varchar which cause error while inserting that value in database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The migration selects data from one table and inserts the data into another table. While inserting, the sequelize adds backslash escape in varchar 'v_occupation' value which is throwing error in insertion.

I have tried replacements and replace on v_occuption but all in vain

```
const queryToUpdateExistingTable = 
`INSERT INTO social_profile ( fk_user_id , fk_marital_status_id ,fk_military_service_id , v_occupation , fk_education_id , v_bio ,v_pets ,v_places_lived ) 
VALUES (:fk_user_id , :fk_marital_status_id, :fk_military_service_id, :v_occupation , :fk_education_id , :v_bio, :v_pets , :v_places_lived) 
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(queryToUpdateExistingTable, 
{type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
replacements: {fk_user_id: uProfileData.id ,
               fk_marital_status_id:uProfileData.fk_marital_status_id,
                                fk_military_service_id: uProfileData.fk_military_service_id,
                                v_occupation: uProfileData.v_occupation,
                                fk_education_id: uProfileData.fk_education_id,
                                v_bio: uProfileData.v_bio,
                                v_pets: uProfileData.v_pets,
                                v_places_lived: uProfileData.v_places_lived
                            }});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `v_occupation` directly into the query string instead of using replacements. You can insert it by using `+` to add the strings or use [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert values using placeholders in strings enclosed by backticks.

```
const queryToUpdateExistingTable = `
INSERT INTO social_profile 
(
    fk_user_id,
    fk_marital_status_id,
    fk_military_service_id,
    v_occupation,
    fk_education_id,
    v_bio,
    v_pets,
    v_places_lived
)
VALUES 
(
    :fk_user_id,
    :fk_marital_status_id,
    :fk_military_service_id,
    ${uProfileData.v_occupation},
    :fk_education_id,
    :v_bio,
    :v_pets,
    :v_places_lived
)`
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(queryToUpdateExistingTable, {
    type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
    replacements: {
        fk_user_id: uProfileData.id,
        fk_marital_status_id: uProfileData.fk_marital_status_id,
        fk_military_service_id: uProfileData.fk_military_service_id,
        fk_education_id: uProfileData.fk_education_id,
        v_bio: uProfileData.v_bio,
        v_pets: uProfileData.v_pets,
        v_places_lived: uProfileData.v_places_lived
    }
})
```